# PHP List Content of .txt files from folder

Tags: php, jquery, html

On my website, I have an upload story feature with a user written title and story. It uploads it as a text file in a directory. Is there a way to list the content of these files using php or anything? Also, I'd like to only show like 200 chars of the story, and have a 'show full story' button, that would show the full story (I'll use jQuery for this).

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+reading+text+file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dataArray = array();
//Number of chars for the string
$num = 200;

//Check if DIR exists
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    //Loop over the directory
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        //Strip out the . and .. files
        if ($file != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $dataArray[] = array();
            //Store file contents
            $filecontent = file_get_contents($file);
            //Split the content and store in array
            $length = strlen($filecontent);
            $dataArray[] = array(substr($filecontent, 0, $num), substr($filecontent, $num, $length )); 
        }
    }
    //close the dir
    closedir($handle);
}
```

With this you get an array with all the content of your .txt files, splittet into 2 Strings, one with 200 chars the other with the rest.

The string with 200 length is $dataArray[x][0] and the other is $dataArray[x][1].

Now you can use this in HTML:

```
<?php foreach($dataArray as $data) { ?>
    <div class="visible">
        <?php echo $data[0]; ?>
    </div> 
    <div class="hidden">
        <?php echo $data[1]; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

in php.net:
to open a directory:
opendir() http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

```
$dir = opendir('/path/to/files');
```

to read the directory (you can loop):
readdir() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

```
while (false !== ($file= readdir($dir))) {
        //$file has the filename
    }
```

to get the content of a file:
file_get_contents() http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php

```
$content=file_get_contents($file);
```